# How to delete account folder from desktop?

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, user-folders

Somehow an account folder has appeared the desktop. An attempt to delete it results in request for Admin permission. The folder doesn't  show up as a shortcut, instead looks like a normal folder with a person next to it
 Operating system is windows 8.1

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the issue?

That would help people see your perspective a little better.

Comment: I agree with @CheesusCrust, a screenshot would help. Are you the admin of your computer? Have you tried removing it in Safe Mode?

Comment: Which account this folder belongs to.

Comment: Try this http://superuser.com/questions/708139/how-to-delete-a-users-folder-in-windows-8-1

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on desktop
2. Personalize
3. Change desktop icons (on the top left)
4. Uncheck "User's files"

Comment: It only hides `%UserProfile%` but that might be the issue described in the question :)